# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' despite User ID in the connection string

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, sql-server

I have a visual web part that is calling a database. I’m using a connection string that passes through a SQL account and password to access the DB. This works when trying to access a DB on the same server, but when I try to access a different server I am getting the error

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

The only difference between the two is that the SQL database is located on a different server, so it seems like the credentials aren’t being passed through to the other server.

I’ve had a look online and it’s seems like this is being referred to as the “Double Hop Problem”, but that seems to be related to a windows accounts rather than a SQL Login.

The SQL version is SQL Server 2008. Do I need to specify something in the connection string to pass the credentials through to the other server?

Comment: May need to use Kerberos?  I'm not an expert on Kerberos, so I won't hazard an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that the issue is not related to SQL login, I think it may occur because of

> The Application pool user account of the SharePopint web application didn't have permission to access the Database.

**Solution**

- In the SQL server, Provide the Application pool user account the required permission on your database as Owner.
- In your `Connection String` tag,

  - Change the `Connection String` from `SQL authentication` to `Windows Authentication` by removing the userID and Password.
  - And add `Integrated Security = true`

If the above solution does not help check another thread at [Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59af79e7-bb18-4e2f-b11c-28a66c90a5e2/login-failed-for-user-nt-authorityanonymous-logon?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: This defeats the purpose -- the OP indicated they're attempting to use a SQL login. You've just introduced an issue where by you now do have a double hop scenario due to lack of Kerberos.

Comment: So I mentioned the Kerberos solution at the attached link

Comment: Understood, but it doesn't solve OPs problem -- namely that SQL auth isn't functional. Keep in mind that not all types of SQL servers have WIA.

Comment: Yes unfortunately we were attempting to use SQL authentication to keep things consistent as this is the account we use for SSRS reports as well. This is a corporate environment and I may not be allowed use the app pool account.